# Striping brackets from csv output in python

Tags: python, list, csv

I have this code where I merge 2 files:

```
f1 = open('file.csv', 'r')
f2 = open(file2.csv', 'r')
f3 = open('results.csv', 'w')

c1 = csv.reader(f1)
c2 = csv.reader(f2)
c3 = csv.writer(f3)

file2 = list(c2)

for file1_row in c1:
    row = 1
    found = False
    results_row = file1_row  
    for file2_row in file2:        
        x = file2_row[1:]
        if file1_row[0] == file2_row[0]:
            results_row.append(x)
            found = True
            break
    row += 1
    if not found:
        results_row.append('Not found')     
    c3.writerow(results_row)

f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()
```

the output is:

```
455, E+13, 5.05, 12, 378, BDAP, BT28, I, NSW, ['0.000000', '20140723', '20170803']

484, E+13, 5.05, 2.0, 204, LAP, 3G2, A, NSW, ['2.980000', '20150714', '20180217']
```

How do I remove the "[]" and the "'" from the added fields? 
I want the output to be:

```
455, E+13, 5.05, 12, 378, BDAP, BT28, I, NSW, 0.000000, 20140723, 20170803

484, E+13, 5.05, 2.0, 204, LAP, 3G2, A, NSW, 2.980000, 20150714, 20180217
```

Comment: Maybe try `results_row.extend(x)` instead of `results_row.append(x)`. It's hard to tell what this code is doing.

Comment: Thank you @RoadRunner Yep- this works perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're appending a list to a list. What you really want to do is `extend` the first list with each item of the second list:

```
>>> c1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> c2 = ['a', 'b']
>>> c1.append(c2)
>>> c1
[1, 2, 3, ['a', 'b']]
>>> c1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> c1.extend(c2)
>>> c1
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b']
```

See the [sequence operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations)

Answer (score 1):

As @JoshSmeaton said, using `extend` rather than `append` can make it.

I just post another method in case situations where you already get a nested list, and can't change how the list adds new element.

```
flatList = []

def unfold(X):
    for x in X:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            unfold(x)
        else:
            flatList.append(x)
```

Input:

```
nestedList = [1, 2, [3, 4, 5]]
unfold(nestedList)
print(flatList)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Careful with unfolding lists containing strings if you use this.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton Thanks. Updated the answer.